# Conditional Table Style on specific text in First row

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am very new to VBA so apologies for this BASIC question. I've tried to Google it in vain for a week. I have several table styles in a 200 page document, about 300 tables altogether. Can I apply a specific table style depending on there being a specific text (say, "Table") in the first row? here is my embarrassing Neanderthal first attempt, which works so far.

```
Sub FormatMyTablesTwo()

Dim oTb As Table
For Each oTb In ActiveDocument.Tables
With oTb
    .Style = "Table Grid Light"
    .PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPercent
    If .Columns.Count > 1 Then
'If more than one column then horizontals only
                .Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    
                .Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalUp).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
    ElseIf .Columns.Count = 1 Then
' If 1 column then borders only
                .Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                .Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                .Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
                .Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
               .Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                .Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalDown).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                .Borders(wdBorderDiagonalUp).LineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
' Need to use specific Table style if first column says "Table" 
' ???

     End If
        .Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowRight
        .PreferredWidth = 85
 End With
Next oTb
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite easy to get the text of a cell but you need to remove the two character end of cell marker before trying to compare it. The example below gets the text of the first cell of the first row.

```
  'get cell text and remove the end of cell marker
  Dim cellText As String
  cellText = Left(.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, Len(.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text) - 2)
  If cellText = "Text I want to Find" Then
    'do something
  End If
```